# Execute attached property after UI render

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I have a text block on UI which gets populated from Resource file by using binding source. Now I have attached dependency property type of bool which checks if true then it concatenate "(*)" sign to text block.

But at run time, when screen gets loaded attached proeprty gets execute first before the text is gets binded from resource file and due to this sign added by attached property gets overriden by binding.

**Dependency Proerty**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsRequired", typeof(bool), typeof(RequiredIndicator),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange, OnIsRequiredChanged));
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static Resources:Resource.ColorTextBlockText}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"
                   Style="{StaticResource AdminScreenTextBlockStyle}" Resources:RequiredIndicator.IsRequired="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a `Converter`?

You don't want to modify the bound value, otherwise your actual data value will either contain the `(*)` on the end of it, or the binding will be lost. A converter will simply convert the bound value to add the `(*)` on the end for display purposes only.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding 
               Source={x:Static Resources:Resource.ColorTextBlockText}, 
               Converter={StaticResource RequiredIndicatorConverter}" 
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"
           Style="{StaticResource AdminScreenTextBlockStyle}" />
```

Otherwise, you can try and use the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) to run your code at a later [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) than `DispatcherPriority.Render`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really force things to be updated in the "correct" order. Your best bet would be to add another attached property, such as:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(RequiredIndicator),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsParentArrange, OnIsRequiredChanged));
```

Then you would use the combination of `IsRequiredProperty` and `MyTextProperty` to set the `TextBlock.TextProperty`. Then you'd set `MyTextProperty` to the resource.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are trying to alter the text received from the resource, however the code for the Text property gets executed BEFORE **Resources:RequiredIndicator.IsRequired="True"**.
This some times happens to me and could be able to solve it by arranging the properties in XAML. This is not the preferred method as it is not always warrantied to work.
It seems that a Converter could do the magic as is warranted to be executed first before the Text property gets the value.